# How to set proxy for SFTP in Ubuntu terminal

Tags: ubuntu, sftp

I set the proxy for curl and wget using the commands:

```
export http_proxy="http://xxx.xx.xx.xx:8080"
export https_proxy="https://xxx.xx.xx.xx:8080"
```

These work. So I tried

```
export sftp_proxy="http://xxx.xx.xx.xx:8080"
export sftp_proxy="https://xxx.xx.xx.xx:8080"
```

But the connection times out.

Answer (score 0):

OpenSSH does not use these environment variables. To tunnel your SSH connections through an HTTP CONNECT proxy, you'll need to find a dedicated proxy client and put it in OpenSSH's `ProxyCommand` option.
– either using ssh's `-o` option in the command line or using the `~/.ssh/config` configuration file, whichever you prefer.

One common HTTP proxy client is `proxytunnel`, which can be used as:

```
Host *
    ProxyCommand "proxytunnel -p xxx.xx.xx.xx:8080 -d %h:%p"
```

If you need HTTPS to access the proxy itself, add the `-E` option to proxytunnel (not to ssh).

(Typically it's either `http:` **or** `https:`, unless they're on different ports – your original example of using it both ways on the same port 8080 seems a bit odd. How you access the proxy itself is separate from what you tunnel through the proxy.)